# SJS supports for custom filterModule class

Tags: jspresso

I've created a subclass of "FilterableBeanCollectionModule" class for some specific needs... Now I need to instantiate a "filterModule" using my subclass...

How can I setup an SJS "filterModule" to use my subclass ?

Moreover, I would like to parameterize the generated bean (i.e my subclass instance) with some custom parameters... Is it possible to manage that ?

Answer (score 0):

This [RFE](https://github.com/jspresso/jspresso-ce/issues/50) has just been implemented for Jspresso 4.2-SNAPSHOT. It allows the `class` and `custom` attributes on the different module declarations (`simpleModule`, `beanModule`, `collectionModule`, `filterModule`).

Whenever you cannot switch to the 4.2-SNAPSHOT, then your only option is to go for plain Spring in your project frontend.xml, which is not very neat, I must admit. Just take the generated Spring declaration from ds-frontend.xml, copy/paste it to your frontend.xml file, and customize it as you like.